# Multiply two columns in a groupby statement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simplified data frame called df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1,1,2,2],
               'price': [12,11,15,13],
               'y': [7,7,9,9]})
```

I want to group by num an then multiply price and y and take the sum divided by sum of y

I've been trying to get started with this and have been having trouble

```
df.groupby('letter').agg(['price']*['quantity'])
```

Comment: Start with `g = df.groupby('num')`, then work with `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to compute a weighted mean

A way to do this is:

```
import numpy as np
# define custom function with 'y'column as weights
weights = lambda x: np.average(x,weights=df.loc[x.index,'y'])
# aggregate using this new function
df.groupby('num').agg({'price': weights})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have exactly similar problem. And I am getting key error for the 'y' column when using this method. Can you please help?

Answer (score 6):

Prior to the groupby operation, you can add a temporary column to the dataframe that calcs your intermediate result (`price * y`) and then use this column in your groupby operation (summing the values, and then using `eval` to calculate the sum of `temp` divided by the sum of `y`).  Cast the result back to a dataframe and call the new column whatever you'd like.

```
>>> (df
     .assign(temp=df.eval('price * y'))
     .groupby('num')
     .sum()
     .eval('temp / y')
     .to_frame('result')
)
     result
num        
1      11.5
2      14.0
```

Comment: here I want to multiply (price * y) and then divide this by sum of y. how can that be achieved?

FYI, I don't want to take the sum of the multiplication

Comment: @NitinKothari New question please with expected result and what you've tried.